# Magento Large Database Backup/Restore Failed

Tags: database, magento, backup, restore

I have a large database (about 244 MB+) and now I want to transfer it to other location from production to development server for fixing the bugs, upgrading and also backup. The hosting provider is Siteground.com

When I try to make a backup of magento database using magento backend Backup utility, phpMyAdmin or from Navicat for MySQL, unfortunately it fails each time showing no error.

I need Magento community help. What should I do to accomplish the backup successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

~Shaman

Comment: Have you tried with `mysqldump -uroot dbname > backup.sql` ?

Answer (score 0):

If it fails by showing a blank screen only then it likely means PHP ran out of time or memory, either way reducing the size of the import would help.

You can often save a lot of space by [clearing logs](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-knowledge-base/speed-up-magento-product-import-export-and-general-via-the-database/) prior to the export. Also, you can export-import some tables separately to spread the work over two operations, phpMyAdmin has a table selection box on the export page.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line MySQL to dump and add an extra flag --single-transaction

mysqldump -hHOSTNAME -uUSERNAME DBNAME --single-transaction -p > myfile.sql

For a 250MB database, you shouldn't have any bother.

As above, [flushing Magento log entries](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-knowledge-base/speed-up-magento-product-import-export-and-general-via-the-database/) will help too, but I can't imagine there is too many in a 250MB DB.